# How do you use Spring RestDocs to document the fields of WebFlux responses?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-restdocs

I have an API that serves up responses as `Flux` and `Mono` which in turn provides a JSON payload as a Server Send Event.

I am also using `Spring RestDocs` to document the contents of that payload. These are generated in a `WebFluxTest` and an

I am able to generate a simple ResponseBody snippet using `PayloadDocumentation.responseBody()`, but when I try to describe the fields using field descriptors...

```java
@WebFluxTest
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ArticleHandler.class)
class HandlerTest { 
...

    @Test
    void testGetArticle() {
        webClient.get()
                .uri("/articles/{id}", "article-id")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk().expectBody().consumeWith(
                        document("article", PayloadDocumentation.responseFields(fieldWithPath("id")
                        .type(JsonFieldType.STRING)
                        .description("Unique ID for blog article")));
    }
}
```

I get the following failing test:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Cannot handle text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8 content as it could not be parsed as JSON or XML
org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadHandlingException: Cannot handle text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8 content as it could not be parsed as JSON or XML
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.ContentHandler.forContentWithDescriptors(ContentHandler.java:69)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.createModel(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:157)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:78)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:191)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.webtestclient.WebTestClientRestDocumentation.lambda$document$0(WebTestClientRestDocumentation.java:77)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultBodyContentSpec.lambda$consumeWith$3(DefaultWebTestClient.java:564)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.ExchangeResult.assertWithDiagnostics(ExchangeResult.java:206)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultBodyContentSpec.consumeWith(DefaultWebTestClient.java:564)
    at com.project.blog.article.HandlerTest.testGetArticle(HandlerTest.java:62)
```

Are there any way that I can document the objects emitted in my `text/event-stream` payload?

Comment: Have you tried removing `.type(JsonFieldType.STRING)`?

Comment: It kicks back with the same message.

Comment: It's hard to advise without some more details. For example, does every event in the stream have the same structure? If so, you could perhaps write an operation preprocessor that modifies the response content to extract the JSON from a single event and then use REST Docs to document that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: For reference, here is the full class in "action": https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-from-the-jvm-ecosystem/blob/master/tck/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples/jvm/tck/TckTest.java#L221-L257

I followed [Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) advice and implemented a preprocessor like this:

```java
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.preprocessResponse;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.requestFields;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.responseFields;


import org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor;

class Whatever {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("GET /api/movies")
    void verifyGetListOfMovies(@Autowired WebTestClient webclient) {
    
        var movies = webclient.get().uri("/movies")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectHeader().value(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                s -> {
                    var mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType(s);
                    var compatibleMediaTypeReturned = mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM) ||
                                                      mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    assertThat(compatibleMediaTypeReturned).isTrue();
                })
            .expectBodyList(Movie.class)
            .consumeWith(document("movies", preprocessResponse(new ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor(
                    (bytes, mediaType) -> {
                        var result = new StringBuilder().append("[");
                        try (var scanner = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), mediaType.getCharset()).useDelimiter("(\r?\n){2}")) {
                            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                                String statement = scanner.next().trim().replaceAll("^data: *", "").trim();
                                if (statement.isEmpty()) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                result.append(statement).append(",");
                            }
                        }
                        result.replace(result.length() - 1, result.length(), "]");
                        return result.toString().getBytes(mediaType.getCharset());
                    })
            ), responseFields(
                fieldWithPath("born").description("The year in which the person was born."),
                fieldWithPath("name").description("The name of the person."),
                fieldWithPath("id").description("The neo4j internal id."))
            ))
            .returnResult()
            .getResponseBody();
    }
}
```